# excel vba It is possible to create a variable according to cell value?

Tags: excel, vba

It is possible in Excel VBA to create a variable (or indexes in an array) according to a cell value? I mean "on the fly", because values in the cell can change.

For example, if column A looks like

```
item1
item1
item1
item2
item2
```

(I paste different data in column A, so the number of items name as well as their  names can change).

I can extract unique values with

```
Set dU1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
lrU = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
cU1 = Range("A4:A" & lrU)
For iU1 = 1 To UBound(cU1, 1)
    dU1(cU1(iU1, 1)) = 1
Next iU1
```

Now `dU1` has two keys: `item1` and `item2`.

What I want to do now is to create the variables `VarItem1` and `VarItem2` (or a multidimensional array: the first dimension would be numbers that represents the variables).
Can this be done in VBA? Something like in php, where you can retrieve data from database and create an array according to that data:

```
$result = $link->query("SELECT A,B FROM mytable");
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){ 
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        $_SESSION[$row[0]][] = ($row[1]);
    }
 }
```

Comment: I don't know anything about php. But putting a range of cells into an array is rather easy in VBA: `Dim vArray() As Variant` and then `vArray = Range("A4:A" & lrU)`. Done.

Comment: Yes, but I'm looking for a multidimensional array. Suppose we define `item1` as `0` and `item2` as `1`. I would like to generate this array: `(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(1,0),(1,1)`. The first number of each pair refers to `item1` or `item2`, whereas the second to each repetition (three for `item1` and two for `item2` in the example above).

Comment: You can create a multidimensional array in VBA... Just parse item1 wtih strcomp("item1", cells(row,column))=0 then myarray(0,counter)=value... You have to redim and save values and do the for loop...etc.

Comment: My problem is that I want a template that can handle different data. So, while on one ocasion in column A values could be `item1` and `item2`, on another column A values could be `drought`, `control` and `watered`. So I cannot use strcomp against a fixed value ("item1") like you said. But I think your response is helpful: I may include a subloop that strcomp `dU1.keys()(i)` to the cell value. Thanks!